# How to use prettier to handle the line breaks of ">" and "{{" or ">" and "}}"?

Tags: html, vue.js, prettier

### environment:

- vue  2.6.12
- vscode 1.56.2
- prettier v6.4.0

---

when I use Prettier to format my code , it will return

```
<el-tab-pane
  v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
  :key="index"
  :label="tab.title"
  :name="tab.name"
  >{{ tab.title }}</el-tab-pane
>
```

But I actually want this,so I should I can only manually change it :

```
<el-tab-pane
  v-for="(tab, index) in tabs"
  :key="index"
  :label="tab.title"
  :name="tab.name"
>
  {{ tab.title }}
</el-tab-pane>
```

Could I just use prettier to achive this goal?

My prettier config is:

```
module.exports = {
  semi: false,
  singleQuote: true,
  tabWidth: 2,
  bracketSpacing: true,
  endOfLine: 'auto',
  printWidth: 80,
  trailingComma: 'none',
  arrowParens: 'always',
  proseWrap: 'preserve',
  jsxBracketSameLine: true
}
```

Comment: vue 2.6.12 is not an environment. What Vue prettier plugin do you use? What is your current Prettier config?

Comment: Updated. pleace have a look

Comment: Please, list the exact config, including relevant package versions. There are several ways to use Prettier. I didn't see the problem you describe in proper vue+eslint+prettier setup.